# ViewPager is not working correctly after device rotation

Tags: android, rotation, android-viewpager

After rotation, one old page is displayed, followed by new pages.
Before rotation [1](https://yadi.sk/i/pv7ShcfApb5jhw).
After rotation [2](https://yadi.sk/i/D4IqF_c0aCCMBw).

Layout with ViewPager:

```
<RelativeLayout ...
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment with this layout:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    val view =  inflater.inflate(layoutId(), container, false)
    view.findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.pager).adapter = TextPagerAdapter(activity!!.supportFragmentManager, listOf())
    return  view
}
```

TextPagerAdapter:

```
override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment = PageFragment.newInstance("sssssss ssss $position")

    override fun getCount() = 5//pageText.size
}
```

PageFragment:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(layoutId(), container, false)
    view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.page_content_textView).text = arguments!!.getCharSequence(PAGE_TEXT)
    return view
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to check if the content fragment is already created.
The solution is to check if the savedInstanceState == null. And create new fragment if that condition is true.

In MyActivity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    if(savedInstanceState == null) this.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .add(containerViewId, CollectionDemoFragment()).commit()
}
```